# Why None change to null automatically in F#

Tags: f#

When try the following code in F# interactive

```
> let a = None
- let b = (a, Some 1);;    
> b;;
val it : 'a option * int option = (null, Some 1)
```

It show that b has type **'a option * int option**, the type of b is correct. However, the value of first element of the tuple is null, not None, Why?

When try to verify the first element of the tuple whether really is null

```
printfn "%s" (match b with (null, _) -> "null" | _ -> "not null");;
```

it gives the following error

> error FS0043: The type ''a option' does not have 'null' as a prope r
>   value

When try to get the fisrt value in tuple,

```
let c = fst b;;
```

it gives

> error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'c' has been inferred to 
>   have generic type
>       val c : '_a option Either define 'c' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit argume nts or, if you do not intend for it
>   to be generic, add a type annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internal representation for the value `None` is indeed a `null` value. But that is the internal representation, the compiler identifies `null` and `None` as two completely different values, so you cannot compare them as they are different types. That is why you get: `error FS0043`.

This is actually something to be careful of:

```
let a = None
let b = (a, Some 1) 

let print  v = printfn "%A" v

sprintf "%A" a     |> print   // "<null>"
sprintf "%A" b     |> print   // "(None, Some 1)"
sprintf "%O" a     |> print   // "<null>"
sprintf "%O" b     |> print   // "(, Some(1))"
string       a     |> print   // ""
string       b     |> print   // "(, Some(1))"
a      .IsNone     |> print   // true
a      .IsSome     |> print   // false
a      .GetType()  |> print   // System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
a      .ToString() |> print   // System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
(fst b).ToString() |> print   // System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
(snd b).ToString() |> print   // "Some(1)"
```

... because calling some methods on a `None` value throws the dreaded `NullReference` Exception and converting to string is also erratic.

Regarding `error FS0030` basically values cannot be generic. This has been discussed many times in SO.

Values from Discriminated Unions seem to be treated in a special way, they seem to be granted an exception, for instance these are generic and still Ok:

```
type MyDU<'A, 'B> =
| ValNo
| ValA of 'A
| ValB of 'B

let v1 = ValNo   // MyDU<'a,'b> double generic but Ok
let v2 = ValA 1  // MyDU<int,'a> generic but Ok
let v3 = ValB 1  // MyDU<'a,int> generic but Ok
```

but these are not Ok

```
let valNo() = ValNo
let valA  a = ValA a
let valB  b = ValB b

let w1 = valNo()   // MyDU<'_a,'_b> double generic not Ok
let w2 = valA 1  // MyDU<int,'_a> generic not Ok
let w3 = valB 1  // MyDU<'_a,int> generic not Ok
```

Comment: Thank for your detail explanation. for the last example, Is it means that cannot return value from a function that still have generic type variable which no specific concrete type? It seems no way to return value of MyDU<'A, 'B> type from a function, right?

Comment: I should clarify, generic values are only a problem when the compiler cannot deduce by itself all the generic types. In the example above, if later on the compiler can deduce the correct types then the error message disappears. An expression like `if w2 = w1 then w3 else w2` lets the compiler deduce that they are all of type `MyDU<int, int>` and then all is well. Alternatively using a type annotation can also solve the problem.

Comment: Thank for you clarify. for the original problem, if use type annotation as you mention as above comment: let c:int option = fst b, we can get back the first None element in tuple. It seems just the display problem of F# interactive, it  is no harm in daily programming.